# Cannot get object from RLMResult (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have code in swift (realm v0.88.0), for other model its works but only for this type I get this bug

```
var result = Type.objectsInRealm(RLMRealm.defaultRealm(), withPredicate: NSPredicate(format: "id == %i",0)) as RLMResults

println("result \(result)------- count \(result.count), obj \(result.firstObject())")
```

And print result

```
result RLMResults <0x16525400> (
    [0] Type {
        id = 0;
        msg = Vacation;
    },
    [1] Type {
        id = 0;
        msg = Vacation;
    }
)------- count 2, obj
```

I cannot get lastobject(), objectAtIndex(0), [0] all return nil

As for me its some bug in realm, but maybe somebody was met same problem and successful resolved it

Comment: Please add the code you can not get to work and the related output.

Comment: As a side comment you can simplify your first line a lot when you use the default realm:
    let result = Type.objectsWhere("id == 0")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
let results = Type.objectsWhere("id == 0")
println("first object: \(results[0])")
// or
println("first object: \(results.objectAtIndex(0))")
```

If it doesn't work for you, please create an issue with enough information for us to reproduce at https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues